# Using repositories in a ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository

I'm building a web application using ASP.NET MVC and i would like use Repository pattern with Unit Of Work pattern, but i have some questions.

First, Who should inherit the IDisposable interface? The repository interface, or the class that implements the repository.
Ex:

**Repository interface:**

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
}
```

Or

**Repository interface:**

```
public interface IRepository<T> : where T : class
{
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable , IRepository<T> where T : class
{
}
```

What is the difference between these two methods of creating repository.

Who should inherit the IDisposable interface? The interface or class that implements the repository?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the IDisposable interface on the Repository class, not it's interface. From a code perspective, both would work, but disposing the Repository instance is part of the work the implementation of the class has to do. Since IDisposable should be internal to the Repository Class, there is no need to call methods of this interface from other parts of the code.